# Github Search Api with Pagination?

Tags: ios, pagination, github-api

I want to use the Github search API Restfully in my iOS application to query public repositories based on 'language' (programming language) as the primary parameter for the search.

From the API documentation i  can understand that the following api gives me what i need.

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc

Although, this returns 370 such repositories for the particular language.

I want to implement pagination in the iOS app so that i can fetch around 10-30 entires at a time only. I have seen that github provides pagination for some of their Api's.

However when i try the following api's with the 'page' and 'per_page' included in the parameter i still get the same results, not limited to the page or the per_page i want.

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc&page=1&per_page=10

Does the github api provide pagination for this search api?
If so what am i missing? How do i go about using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `total_count` is the total number of repositories, not the number of itens that are in the JSON.

The pagination is working as expected, try this and see the result, the number of itens in each request is 10 (as you set in the last parameter "per_page)

Do a `crtl+f` by `full_name`, it will be easier to see the number of itens per request

Check the result of this 2 requests.

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc&page=1&per_page=10

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc&page=2&per_page=10

Comment: Oh yes, this does work. I assumed total_count to be the number of results in the JSON! If we do not include the page parameter it seems like the search api always returns 30 entires?

Comment: Because of the size, it will never return all elements, the "default" value is 30, it can be up to 100 using per_page.

Comment: If the total_count field indicates the total number of repositories, how come there are only 100 pages if per_page is 10? 10 * 100 != 1'726 (state today 12/1 2 PM).

Curious where my thought process goes wrong.

Comment: 100 restriction is for result list count for each page. I think you can have enormous amount of page but you can have maximum of 100 object in a page. So if you have 10000 total count then you have to walk through 100 page with 100 result in each. @Omnibyte, I hope it will work like this since I will need it tomorrow :)

Comment: I tried it now and it return error object as below; {
  "message": "Only the first 1000 search results are available",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/search/"
}

Comment: @Ulysses Sagar: Hello. I'm a Swift newbie and I had exactly the same question as Sagar had. Thank you so much for asking this and thank you for telling me the solution!!